# Procedure for Plotting FFT in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, plot, fft

When plotting FFT results in MATLAB, I usually do it the following way.

```
X = raw_data;
L = length(x);
NFFT = 2^nextpow2(L);
fftx = fft(X,NFFT);
AbsX = abs(fftx);
```

I plot these values of `AbsX` with a properly defined frequency axis. I was just going through some MATLAB examples and came across another procedure like this.

```
y=fft(X,NFFT);
m = y.*conj(y)/NFFT;
```

And they have plotted the values of `m`.

My questions are:

- What is the purpose of this procedure?
- Will it smooth the peaks in the frequency domain?
- Can anyone give me hints on this?

Comment: y .* the conjugate of y should actually give you abs(y)^2, so it is actually a log scale (log 2) I believe, which sometimes makes the result more readable (but it also has a different mathematical use).

Comment: If all you want is a power spectrum then use MATLAB's [periodogram](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/signal/ref/periodogram.html) function rather than dealing with all the "nuts and bolts" yourself.

Comment: @PaulR I'm interested in FFT spectrum for doing a frequency analysis of vibration  signals.

Comment: @PBCR: sure - but the FFT is just one component of this - what you're most likely interested in is the power spectrum, which is window function + FFT + magnitude + log + plot -- you can do this all yourself or you can use MATLAB's `periodogram` function as I suggested above - it's up to you...

Comment: @PaulR or `pwelch`. I'm always wondering about these plenty of questions who insist on using a simple FT for a spectrum...

Comment: @PCBR, there is no such thing as an "FFT spectrum".

Comment: @A.Donda: yes there seems to be a popular misconception whereby "FFT" is synonymous with "spectrum" (of some kind).

Comment: Yeah..may be you guys are right. I find in most of the vibration monitoring books , authors using FFT vibration spectrum and words like that. Anyways, thanks for the clarification.

Comment: @PaulR  I spent some time trying to understand the periodogram function in MATLAB. unfortunately that happen to be part of DSP tool box which I don't have.

Comment: @PBCR: OK - if you're serious about doing any kind of DSP work then you really ought to have the Signal Processing Toolbox for MATLAB - either ask your manager to pay for this, or consider free alternatives such as Octave, or pylab/matplotlib. Failing that, you'll need to essentially implement `periodogram` yourself - it's not that hard, but it seems a shame to have to re-invent the wheel.

Comment: @PaulR  What do you called this process of multiplying the fft of signal by conjugate of fft? Any specific word in terms of DSP?

Comment: @PCBR, that's a fancy way of computing the magnitude squared of the Fourier transform coefficients.  x * x' = abs(x)^2

Comment: As @PBCR says, it's just calculating the squared magnitude - although mathematically correct it's probably not as efficient as just calculating `(re*re + im*im)`.

Comment: @PaulR You meant `abs` function of MATLAB? But I found the above described procedure in one of the MATLAB documentation files.

Comment: Also, I tried to play around with both the procedures and noticed that `m = y.*conj(y)/NFFT;` gave me more clear and readable peaks in frequency spectrum than just using the `abs` values and plotting them.

Comment: All three methods are mathematically equivalent: `x*x'` == `abs(x)^2` == `(x.re*x.re+x.im*x.im)` - you shouldn't see any difference (apart from your `1/NFFT` scale factor above).

Comment: There is a slight difference in terms of noise. I'll try to dig in further to make myself more familiar with the differences and the different procedures. Thanks for your hints Mr@PaulR